# ListView - Items - ImageView out of item layout

Tags: android, listview, imageview, listitem

I have a list item which i fill with the XML layout below. The layout design in Android studio is just what i want to have in my app, but when i execute my app and fill the images within the items, the image become out of borders.

**Layout snapshot in android studio :**

[image: Layout snapshot in android studio]

**Layout snapshot in app :**

[image: Snapshot within the app]

**The listview XML is below:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1111"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtMeGuess"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtMeGuess">

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEval1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/v1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEval2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/m1"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please your help.

Comment: try after giving fix height and width like `120dp` etc.

Comment: i fixed the height with the perfect value and it worked. Thanks.